# Apache Camel - MethodNotFoundException in Transform

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to use camel routing more dinamically, but i had little trouble.
(I'm using camel-core_2.9.0)

I'm using transform method in the route definition

```
Object methodclass;
String methodname;

context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        from("vm:internal0").
        transform().method(methodclass, methodname).
        to("vm:receiver");
    }
});
```

Now if have this assignment (assuming i've TransformLogic class with "transform" method)

```
methodclass = new TransformLogic();
methodname = "transform";
```

i haven't problem, but if i have this assignment

```
methodclass = TransformLogic.class;
methodname = "transform";
.
.
```

Camel thrown`

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route3 at: >>> Transform[bean{java.lang.Class, method=transform}] <<< in route: Route[[From[vm:internal0]] -> [Transform[bean{java.lang.Clas... because of org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with name: transform not found on bean: class core.compoundterm.primitiveterm.DefaultTransformLogic of type: java.lang.Class
```

Where i'm wronging?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Make sure TransformLogic class has either a
- default no-arg constructor
- or that the method name is a public static method

Comment: thanks for reply! I have default no-arg constructor inTransformLogic class and setting the method to static i receive the same error.. i don't understand why Camel try to find the "transform" method of type java.lang.class??

Comment: Ah this looks like a bug, as it does a .toString to set a name, but then pickup and use the name as a reference for a bean. Will log a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-4997

Comment: A workaround is to pass in an instance instead of the class, that should work.

Comment: I had a look, you are actually doing this a bit wrong, but will improve Camel. As method has both (Object) and (Class) as type, when when you pass in where it fails, then it becomes a (Object) type by the compiler. You would have to cast it to (Class) to make it work. I will add a special check in Camel for this, so it will work out of the box in the next releases.

Comment: Ok Clause.. thanks a lot, i wanted to use object 'methodclass' dinamically, not knowing at runtime the dynamic type of this instance. hence doing a cast cannot resolve my specific problem (surely it helps to bypass the problem).